# how to align elements inside div into 2-3 rows when on mobile (responsive)

Tags: css, angular, alignment, row, responsive

so i have a div which renders the categories of my website. when using mobile this div is too long and it messes the screen width. so i want to turn this div into 2 or even 3 rows when using mobile. a part of the problem is the elements inside this div are dynamic and im not sure how i can align them in 2 rows exactly at the point i want to break it into a new row since its all dynamic...

this is my html:

```
<div class="categories-container">
    <mat-button-toggle-group #group="matButtonToggleGroup" name="fontStyle" aria-label="Font Style" value={{selectedCategory}}>
        <mat-button-toggle class="categories" *ngFor="let category of categories; let i = index" (click)="selectedChanged(group.value)" value="{{category._id}}">{{category.name}}</mat-button-toggle>
    </mat-button-toggle-group>
</div>
```

this is my css:

```
.categories-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 300px;
    left: 680px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .categories-container {
        position:static;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        padding-top: 5px;
    }
}
```

note: changing the width didnt help.

photos for explanition:

right now it looks like this on mobile: https://ibb.co/0JCVDfY

i want it to be like that: https://ibb.co/DGSmnF2

Comment: What you have said in question is different than of your accepted answer.

Comment: you are right but this answer gives the best result for user expreince

Comment: Yes that is correct, I have given my answer as per what you have asked in your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `overflow:auto` for .categories-container

Answer (score 0):

demo in this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-kkfvcg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css)

You just need to set `mat-button-toggle-group`  class property.

```
mat-button-toggle-group {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

and list is adjusted according to width available. row by row.